# Websharper HighCharts Example

Tags: highcharts, f#, websharper

It couldn't find the JQuery and Highcharts packages so I had to download them from nuget. Besides that I am running the example as a single page application.

It doesn't run and I get the following errors:

Error   3   Failed to deserialize metadata for: IntelliFactory.WebSharper.Highcharts, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=dcd983dec8f76a71 ...\packages\WebSharper.3.0.1.73-alpha\build\WebSharper.targets 55  5   DataEnvironment.FWeb

Fixed this by updating to the pre-release versions - but still getting the following bug:

Error   2   Failed to compile assembly with WebSharper.

and:

Error   1   Failed to translate property assignment: Categories.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using a version of the Highcharts extension that doesn't match WebSharper 3.0, install the latest prerelease. jQuery is part of the WebSharper package and the other JavaScript extensions are available on NuGet.

Comment: Thanks, I updated for the pre-release versions but I am still getting: Failed to compile assembly with Websharper

Comment: Can you post your code in order to reproduce the error?

Comment: I just tried the sample and it worked fine, did you change something? The "Failed to translate ..." error occurs when a program element isn't associated with the [<JavaScript>] attribute.

Comment: No, I didnt change anything.. I recreated the project and now it compiles but I dont see anything when I run it.. Is it possible to run it from the single page application template?

Comment: Did you follow the steps described at http://websharper.com/docs/running-snippets ? We are working on making the samples easier to try out, but for now that is how you need to do it.

Comment: @user1129988 I suggest you read the guide that Loïc mentioned, you can get the Highcharts sample to work in a SPA using [this code](http://pastebin.com/3HcD5gTP) in Client.fs. I think that the Highcharts dependencies aren't picked up in your case.